# How is it possible that $dx = \varepsilon$?

Tags: calculus, infinitesimals

Let's consider graph of function $y=x^2$ ("Calculus with infinitesimals" Efraín Soto Apolinar, see picture below).

We have the point $(dx, (dx)^2)$ which coincide with point $(dx, 0)$ and $dx$ isn't nilsquare infinitesimal.
But if we know that $(dx)^2 = 0$ then we can conclude that $dx$ must be nilsquare infinitesimal  $\varepsilon$.
Thus the point $(dx,0)$ coincide with the point $(\varepsilon, 0)$.

I'm confused.

How is it possible that $dx = \varepsilon$ ?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I might just not be familiar with this approach, but it doesn't seem very formal to me.

Comment: Ummmmmmmmmmmmmmm?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $dx$ is a nilsquare infinitesimal.  As mentioned in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4786158/72694), one prefers to use the $dx$ notation when discussing derivatives or related notions such as maxima and minima, as Bell does here.

It is not clear to me what the theoretical background is for Apolinar's remarks.  Is he working in Synthetic Differential geometry?  The way he passes from $dr^2=dx^2$ to $dr=dx$ certainly looks suspicious.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149253/discussion-on-answer-by-mikhail-katz-how-is-it-possible-that-dx-varepsilon); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.